# Cannot edit order or send the email from "sales - orders" inside admin

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, orders, sales-order, edit

We updated to `magento 1.9.2.1` but now we can't edit any order or send the email from the order itself inside "sales - orders"; what could be the reason? CronJobs are working properly.
When I click "edit order" or "send email" inside Firefox error console I read:

> SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: In latest Magento 1.9 emails are being in queue instead of sent directly. queue is being processed via cronjob. set cron job in your server and see if that works.

Comment: Try use [Aoe_Scheduler](https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler) to check cron routines and run it manually.

Comment: also for the edit function it could be a cron issue?

Comment: Looks like a javascript error but not sure if it has to do with sending emails. Editing orders might indeed not work with a javascript error

Comment: Same error here! It is a real interface bug!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Sorry for the Italian in my post, it is a problem strictly related to the italian translation that contains some characters that have to be escaped with a \.

@arredod Ho trovato la soluzione:

Purtroppo è il contrario di quanto dice @7ochem, forse ora Magento 1.9.2.x gestisce da solo i problemi che abbiamo nelle stringhe di lingua: è li il problema.

Nell'html **generato** è:
"Sei sicuro? Quest\\'ordine verrà cancellato e ne verrà creato uno nuovo."

Invece nel file Mage_Sales.csv la stringa di traduzione è:
"Sei sicuro? **Quest\'ordine** verrà cancellato e ne verrà creato uno nuovo."

Quindi magento include esso stesso lo slash.

Basta aprire la traduzione è togliere la **\** davanti quello specifico **apostrofo**.

A me ha funzionato su ben 2 siti con lo stesso problema.

magento/app/locale/it_IT/Mage_Sales.csv @ riga 75

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in the translation file (`Mage_Sales.csv`).
Convert all the single quotes from `'` to `\'`.

Comment: E' il contrario mi sa...